# I want to auto-number a frame title

Tags: beamer, numbering, frame-title

I want to make a quiz with x questions with `beamer`. In the frame title I want to auto-increase the number of the question.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{VRAAG X}
  Dubbelbolle lenzen zijn:
  \begin{enumerate}[A.]
    \item Concave lenzen
    \item<alert@2> Convexe lenzen
    \item Concorde lenzen
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is their an option to do this?

Comment: What number do you want to add? The frame number or the number of the *slide* inside the frame?

Comment: I want to have the number of the question. Kind of like autonumbering figures.

Comment: and how are you generating the number for the questions?

Comment: I can't, @Werner gave me a nice solution (see below) but it's not 100%. When a question is two slides, It doesn't give the numbers correct. So I was thinking something like making a command of question. But my knowledge is not big enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a counter for your questions:

```
\newcounter{vraag}
```

and a command to create the frame title automatically and including the counter

```
\newcommand\VraagTitle{%
  \frametitle{\refstepcounter{vraag}\MakeUppercase{vraag}~\thevraag}}
```

and you need to prevent the counter from stepping from one slide to another inside a single frame

```
\resetcounteronoverlays{vraag}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{vraag}
\newcommand\VraagTitle{%
  \frametitle{\refstepcounter{vraag}\MakeUppercase{vraag}~\thevraag}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{vraag}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\VraagTitle
  Dubbelbolle lenzen zijn:
  \begin{enumerate}[A.]
    \item Concave lenzen
    \item<alert@2> Convexe lenzen
    \item Concorde lenzen
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\VraagTitle
  How many eyes does a honey bee have?
  \begin{enumerate}[A.]
    \item 2
    \item 3
    \item<alert@2> 5
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Insert the frame number as part of the frame title using `\insertframenumber`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{VRAAG \insertframenumber}
  Dubbelbolle lenzen zijn:
  \begin{enumerate}[A.]
    \item Concave lenzen
    \item<alert@2> Convexe lenzen
    \item Concorde lenzen
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{VRAAG \insertframenumber}
  How many eyes does a honey bee have?
  \begin{enumerate}[A.]
    \item 2
    \item 3
    \item<alert@2> 5
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, except that their are some slides before my first question. My first question starts at frame three. So maybe resetting my frame number, but I don't think that would be ok.

Comment: Add `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-2}` somewhere before you start your questions to "take the first two frames away".

Comment: That would do the job, but it is still linked to the frame number. So if I have a question that is two frames, this solution is not 100% fool-proof. (but thanks for the thinking)

Comment: @Arne: There's a difference between a slide and a frame. If you have multiple slides for a single frame, then `\insertframenumber` will stay the same across all slides of that frame. Could you provide a use-case that matches your requirements rather than the current edge-case example in your post?

Comment: thanks for your effort. Question maybe was not well formulated. But the solution was (see below) with a new counter.